# Couldn't decode uint256 from ABI: 0x

Tags: web3js, abi, rpc

I'm trying to get all Transfer events from an account of an ERC721 token, I'm currently struggling with the following error. I googled around but couldn't find much helpful things. I'm definitely on the right network (mainnet) and the contracts are deployed and functional as far as I can tell.

getWeb3.js: https://gist.github.com/adrianmcli/2f42dd98f7d900ec7828930a4a7a1e97

transactions.js

```
  import getWeb3 from "../utils/getWeb3";
  import { MintableNonFungibleToken } from "non-fungible-token-abi";
  import Utils from "web3-utils";
  const web3 = yield getWeb3();

  var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
    MintableNonFungibleToken,
    "0x8c9b261faef3b3c2e64ab5e58e04615f8c788099"
  );
  const addr = "0x0a8e20ee171630ef9dfebf02149169f90c133cd8";
  const events = yield myContract.getPastEvents("Transfer", {
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: "latest",
    topics: [
      Utils.sha3("Transfer(address,address,uint256)"),
      Utils.padLeft(addr, 64)
    ]
  });
  console.log(events);
```

Error

```
 Error: Couldn't decode uint256 from ABI: 0x
    at SolidityTypeUInt.formatOutputUInt [as _outputFormatter] (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:48786:15)
    at SolidityTypeUInt.../../node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/type.js.SolidityType.decode (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:49746:17)
    at http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:49238:49
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ABICoder.../../node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js.ABICoder.decodeParameters (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:49237:13)
    at ABICoder.../../node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js.ABICoder.decodeLog (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:49281:33)
    at Object.../../node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js.Contract._decodeEventABI (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:55150:31)
    at http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:38813:57
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Method.../../node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js.Method.formatOutput (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:38812:23)
```

I checked and I'm getting data from the actual RPC call but it seems web3 cannot process the answer from RPC.

Comment: Could you provide ABI of your contract?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues can lead to the error based on the long thread https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1089

First of all you need to be sure, that your code and ABI synchronized. I mean even small changes in function signatures without updating ABI can lead to the issue.